# My PC that I'm builing resets when I turn it on

Tags: motherboard

I am building a PC. Not all components are installed yet (missing GPU). When I turn it on it powers up and then the fans go silent and the lights turn off for a 5 count then, it turns back on like normal. I'm not sure if the computer is off or it just looks like it.

NOTE: I have all components installed except the graphics card, it's not listed because I haven't chosen it yet.

link to the Part list: https://pcpartpicker.com/list/yb76Hh

Comment: Did you install a speaker? (the magnet looking ones) It should give you a beep code as to why it can't start up

Comment: The behavior you describe is perfectly normal for some motherboard brands.  If the system stays on, after it reboots once, then continue your build.  If you want an answer, you have to confirm it is successfully sitting in UEFI waiting to be configured.